# Cocos2d schedule interval decreaser

Tags: iphone, c, object, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I have made a simple timer but in trying to increase the timers speed over time, so I basically want the timer to have an interval of 1.0 and every 10 seconds I want that timer's interval to decrease by 0.1

How can I go about doing that?

```
[self schedule:@selector(tick:)interval:1.0];
```

That's in the init section

```
-(void)tick:(ccTime)dt{
myTime = myTime+1;
totalTime = myTime; 

[timeLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", totalTime]]; 
}
```

That's the timer.

It's a basic timer which has an interval of 1.0 second, however I would like the interval to decrease by 10% every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in .h file

```
@property(nonatomic,readWrite)CGFloat lastUpdatedInterval;
```

in.m file, initialize self.lastUpdatedInterval = 1.0;

then call

```
[self schedule:@selector(tick:)interval:self.lastUpdatedInterval];
```

in update loop,

```
-(void)tick:(ccTime)dt
{
    if(myTime>9 && (myTime%10 == 0))
    {
      [self unschedule:@selector(tick:)];
      self.lastUpdatedInterval = self.lastUpdatedInterval - (self.lastUpdatedInterval*0.1);
      [self schedule:@selector(tick:)interval:self.lastUpdatedInterval];
    }

myTime = myTime+1;
totalTime = myTime; 

[timeLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", totalTime]]; 

}
```

Comment: just add further condition to prevent it going negative.

Comment: 'code' @property(nonatomic,readWrite)CGFloat lastUpdatedInterval;
'code' can you tell me what that does? thanks

Comment: i tried that but it says: property 'lastUpdatedInterval' requires the method 'setLastUpdatedInterval:' to be defined - use  (at)synthesize, (at)dynamic or provide a method implementation. sorry im new to this. isnt there an easier method?

Comment: in .m file, write @synthesize lastUpdatedInterval; after @ implementation

Comment: thanks mate, i have got it to work, but my timer seems to skip every number 1! lol! so it would go 1..2..3..4..5..6..7..8..9..10..blink..12..etc

Comment: any ideas why the timer skips number all the 1's?

Comment: move this line at the top of the function as first line and try out : myTime = myTime+1;